# Telescoping series of form $\sum (n+1)\cdots(n+k)$

Tags: summation, factorial

Wolfram Alpha is able to telescope sums of the form $\sum (n+1)\cdots(n+k)$

e.g. $(1\cdot2\cdot3) + (2\cdot3\cdot4) + \cdots + n(n+1)(n+2)$

How does it do it?

EDIT: We can rewrite as: $\sum {(n+k)! \over n!} = \sum k!{(n+k)!\over n!k!} = \sum k!{{n+k} \choose n}$
(Thanks *Daniel Fischer*)

EDIT2: We can also multiply out and split sums. So e.g.

$$\sum (n-1)n(n+1) = \sum (n^3-n) = \sum n^3 - \sum n$$

But sums of powers actually seem to be more nasty than the original question, involving Bernoulli numbers.
(Thanks *Claude Leibovici*)

And is there any name for this particular corner of maths? (i.e. How might I go about searching the Internet for information regarding this?)

PS please could we have a 'telescoping' tag?

Comment: Note that the terms are $k!\binom{n+k}{n}$. You probably know a bit about binomial coefficients that helps summing.

Comment: I don't understand why you speak about "telescoping". Beside Daniel Fischer's suggestion, you could also develop $i(i+1)(i+2)= i^3+3 i^2+2 i$ and compute the three sums.

Comment: Is the sum over n or k? Makes a big difference.

Comment: What great answers! Now I am stuck. Both RobJohn and HyperGeometric have nailed it from opposite directions. To accept either answer above the other would not seem right. I guess I will leave it open until SE provides some machinery for resolving these situations.

Comment: @P-i- Thank you!  That's very considerate of you. It was an interesting question, which I enjoyed solving. I've upvoted the question as well.  Have also just posted a comment on a recent observation on its resemblance to the power integral. A related question which you might want to pose would be to find the sum of a series with each term being the reciprocal of the corresponding in the present series, i.e the reciprocal of the product of consecutive integers.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707799/how-to-find-the-sum-of-ii1-cdotsik-for-fixed-k-between-i-1-and-n

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$
\sum_{n=k}^m\binom{n}{k}=\binom{m+1}{k+1}
$$
A generalization is discussed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99672). The equation above is equation $(1)$ with $m=0$.

---

**Telescoping sum**

To turn the sum in the question into a "telescoping sum", we can use the recurrence for Pascal's Triangle:
$$
\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k+1}
$$
Using this recurrence, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=k}^m\binom{n}{k}
&=\sum_{n=k}^m\left[\binom{n+1}{k+1}-\binom{n}{k+1}\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=k+1}^{m+1}\binom{n}{k+1}-\sum_{n=k}^m\binom{n}{k+1}\\
&=\left[\binom{m+1}{k+1}+\color{#C00000}{\sum_{n=k+1}^m\binom{n}{k+1}}\right]-\left[\binom{k}{k+1}+\color{#C00000}{\sum_{n=k+1}^m\binom{n}{k+1}}\right]\\
&=\binom{m+1}{k+1}-\binom{k}{k+1}\\
&=\binom{m+1}{k+1}
\end{align}
$$
The sums in red are the terms that are telescoped out, leaving just the first and last terms. In this case, the last term $\binom{k}{k+1}=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$p_n=\prod_{r=1}^k (n+r)=\overbrace{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k)}^{k \ \text{terms}}$$
which is the product of $k$ consecutive integers.

Consider the difference of two consecutive terms, where each term is the product of $k+1$ consecutive integers, i.e. 
$$\begin{align}
&\prod_{r=1}^{k+1}(n+r)-\prod_{r=0}^k(n+r)\\
&=\overbrace{\underbrace{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k)}_{p_n}(n+k+1)}^{(k+1) \ \text{terms}}-\overbrace{n\underbrace{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k)}_{p_n}}^{(k+1) \ \text{terms}}\\
&=p_n[(n+k+1)-n]\\
&=p_n(1+k)
\end{align}$$

Hence,
$$p_n=\prod_{r=1}^k (n+r)=\frac1{1+k}\left[\prod_{r=1}^{k+1} (n+r)-\prod_{r=0}^k (n+r) \right]$$
which is convenient for telescoping.

Required summation, 
$$\begin{align}
S=\sum_{n=0}^{m}p_n&=\sum_{n=0}^{m} \prod_{r=1}^{k} (n+r)=\sum_{n=0}^{m}(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots (n+k)\\
&=\frac1{k+1}\sum_{n=0}^{m} \left[ \prod_{r=1}^{k+1} (n+r)-\prod_{r=0}^{k} (n+r)\right]\\
&=\frac1{k+1}\prod_{r=1}^{k+1} (m+r) \qquad \blacksquare\end{align}$$
by telescoping.

In your example, $k=3$, hence the general term is

$$(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=\frac14\left[(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)-n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\right]$$

Hence, by telescoping from $n=0$ to $m$,
$$\begin{align}S&=1\cdot2\cdot3+2\cdot3 \cdot 4+\cdots +(m+1)(m+2)(m+3)\\
&=\frac14(m+1)(m+2)(m+3)(m+4) \end{align}$$

---

NB: It is interesting to note that this result bears a striking resemblance to integration.

Compare the standard integral 
$$\int_0^m n^k dn=\frac{m^{k+1}}{k+1}$$
to the result of the summation above, which can also be stated as 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{m}n^{[k]}=\frac {m^{[k+1]}}{k+1}$$
where $n^{[k]}$ is my adjusted* Pochhammer symbol for rising factorials, defined as 
$$n^{[k]}=\prod_{r=1}^{k}(n+r)=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+k)$$

The actual Pochhammer symbol for rising factorials, $n^{(k)}$, starts from $n$ itself and not $n+1$, i.e. 
$$n^{(k)}=\prod_{r=1}^{k}(n+r-1)=n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k-1)$$

Comment: I've upvoted this as it appears valid. But I can't see any clear motivation for the initial algebraic manipulations. Is it possible to rework this logic in a way that does not require inspirational leaps?

Comment: @P-i- - thank you, that's very kind :) in order to make the series telescope, the approach is to convert one term (or product, in this case) into a difference of two terms, usually of a higher 'order'. for instance, to telescope the sum of squares, one would start from the difference of cubes. in this case, we want to sum $k$-term products hence we start from the difference of two consecutive $(k+1)$-term products.

Comment: @P-i- - the proposed solution has been reworked slightly and hopefully this provides greater clarity.

Comment: thanks to all who upvoted. a short appendix has been added to the solution to highlight the resemblance of the summation result to the standard power integral. comments are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, a solution using the combinatorial/binomial approach, as initiated by RobJohn:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let
$p(n, k)
=n(n+1)...(n+k-1)
=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (n+j)
$.

Then
(writing each step in detail)

$\begin{array}\\
p(n+1, k)-p(n, k)
&=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (n+1+j)-\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (n+j)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{k} (n+j)-\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (n+j)\\
&=(n+k)\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} (n+j)-n\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} (n+j)\\
&=((n+k)-n)\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} (n+j)\\
&=k\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} (n+j)\\
&=k\prod_{j=0}^{k-2} (n+1+j)\\
&=kp(n+1, k-1)\\
\end{array}
$

or, 
putting $k+1$ for $k$
and $n$ for $n+1$,
$p(n, k)
=\frac{p(n, k+1)-p(n-1. k+1)}{k+1}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^M p(n, k)
&=\sum_{n=1}^M \frac{p(n, k+1)-p(n-1. k-1)}{k+1}\\
&=\frac1{k+1}\sum_{n=1}^M (p(n, k+1)-p(n-1. k+1))\\
&=\frac1{k+1}(p(M, k+1)-p(0, k+1))\\
&=\frac{p(M, k+1)}{k+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: This proof is succinct and flawless!  Thanks Marty!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\sum_{n = 0}^{m}\pars{n + 1}\ldots\pars{n + k}}=
\sum_{n = 0}^{m}{\pars{n + k}! \over n!}
=k!\sum_{n = 0}^{m}{n + k \choose k}
=k!\sum_{n = 0}^{m}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n + k} \over z^{k + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=k!\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{k} \over z^{k + 1}}
\sum_{n = 0}^{m}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=k!\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{k} \over z^{k + 1}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{m + 1} - 1 \over \pars{1 + z} - 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=k!\bracks{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{\pars{1 + z}^{k + m + 1} \over z^{k + 2}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
-\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{k} \over z^{k + 2}}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=k!\bracks{{k + m + 1 \choose k + 1} - {k \choose k + 1}}
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n = 0}^{m}\pars{n + 1}\ldots\pars{n + k}
> =k!\,{k + m + 1 \choose m}}
> $$

Comment: *blink* complex analysis! That's fantastic! But how does the first path integral come from n+k choose k?

Comment: @P-i- That's an identity:
$$
{a \choose b}=\oint_{0\ <\ \left\vert \,z\,\right\vert\ =\ c}{(1 + z)^a \over z^{b + 1}}\,{{\rm d}z \over 2\pi{\ic}}
$$
It's valid for $c \in {\mathbb R}\,,\ c > 0$ and $b\ =\ 0,1,2,3,\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

Also your terms can be re written as
$$n(n+1)(n+2)=\dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4}-\dfrac{(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}{4}.$$

Comment: that may be correct but it would not telescope readily...

Comment: Now it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Following from RobJohn's hint, this can be proved very simply by reverse-engineering the [hockey-stick identity](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity).

[image: hockey-stick identity]

The blues sum to the red for any given 'hockey-stick'.

It is a straightforward proof by induction.  For example, in the picture, 1+3+6+10+15 = 35, so 1+3+6+10+15 + 21 = 35+21 = 56

i.e. **True(stick length k) => True(stick length k+1)**

Induction can also be argued from the ${n \choose r}$ formula, but the above method avoids algebraic manipulation, working instead from the simple "*each element is formed by summing its upper neighbours*" definition of Pascal's Triangle.

But now we DO need some algebraic manipulation.

We write this hockey-stick identity as:

$${k+0 \choose k} + ... + {k+n \choose k} = {k+(n+1) \choose (k+1)} $$

(notice the hockey stick has been reflected)

$$ {(k+0)! \over {k!((k+0)-k)!}} + ... + {(k+n)! \over {k!((k+n)-k)!}} = {(k+(n+1))! \over {(k+1)!(((k+(n+1))-(k+1))!}}$$

$$ {(k+0)! \over 0!} + ... + {(k+n)! \over n!} = {1 \over {k+1}} \cdot {(k+(n+1))! \over n!}$$

So the original question turns out to be an emergent property of Pascal's Triangle, and I would hazard a guess that it is from this simple construct that the question originally arose.

However, this proof doesn't move forwards from start to finish in a sequence of intelligently chosen moves. It doesn't offer any insight into telescoping general sums, hence I am favouring hypergeometric's proof.

Comment: thank you! glad you liked it :) robjohn's approach using the pascal triangle identity is quite useful too, and i have used a similar approach elsewhere on MSE for another question.

Answer (score 0):

**Induction**

This question is actually a duplicate of: [Finding a closed formula for $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots k +\dots + n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(k+n-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219693/finding-a-closed-formula-for-1-cdot2-cdot3-cdots-k-dots-nn1n2-cdotsk)

But it is difficult to find duplicates when the question can only be expressed using maths symbols, and this question now acts as a more comprehensive resource.

One of the answers to that question is to manually construct formulae for the first few cases: $1+2+3+\dots+n$, $1\cdot2 +\dots + n\cdot(n+1)$, etc, notice a pattern and intuit a candidate formula, then prove this by induction.